# Selenium Web Driver C# InvalidCastException for List of WebElements after JavascriptExecutor

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium web driver with Visual Studios 2010 in C#. 
I'm using a jQuery to filter out a list of divs and use Selenium to double click them. However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of the InvalidCastException.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
IWebDriver m_driver = new ChromeDriver();
IJavaScriptExecutor js = m_driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string jsQuery = [insert some query here that returns list of divs];
object result = js.ExecuteScript(jsQuery);

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list = (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>)result;
```

The result does return a list of webelements though, but for some reason, sometimes the code above runs fine and casts and other times it doesn't on ChromeDriver. When it doesn't work, the last line of code provided fails with the following:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'."
```

On InternetExplorerDriver, it fails almost all the time with the following:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'.
```

I have tried casting it to RemoteWebElement for IE, but that doesn't work either, because it sees RemoteWebElement and not a list of RemoteWebElements, and hence I can't enumerate them later.

Any clues as to why?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see if VS can give you any hints about what exactly is being brought back? Are the elements always visible? Have you tried wrapping it in a WebDriverWait?

Comment: Yes, I included a breakpoint and I get either ReadOnlyCollection or objects, they differ from time to time. The elements are indeed visible and not null. And I did set an implicit wait at least a few seconds. But anyway, I resolved my own issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by doing the following:

```
IWebDriver m_driver = new ChromeDriver();
IJavaScriptExecutor js = m_driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string jsQuery = [insert some query here that returns list of divs];
var result = js.ExecuteScript(jsQuery);
foreach (IWebElement element in (IEnumerable) result){...}
```

This works and no longer throws exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just use `driver.findElements(By.xpath())`?
Any particular reason that you have to go through jQuery?

To get the actual elements from the jQuery list you'll probably have to use [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the objects you're returning from you JavaScript are **actual** HTML elements, and not jQuery-wrapped objects. jQuery may be wrapping the elements inside its own objects, which means that the objects returned from your JavaScript execution aren't actually `IWebElements`.

As an aside, it's not often that it makes sense to use JavaScript for element location. It might be worth an explanation as to why you can't simply use `FindElements()` for your purposes.