# Selenium webdriver System Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#, selenium

To collect some test data for a neural net in C# I want to use Selenium to scrape some dynamically generated data [WSJ](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3022-govtbonds.html?mod=topnav_2_3004). There is an example implementation on the Selenium site that seems to do exactly what I need [Finding all the input elements to the every label on a page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). The example searches on `TagName`, I search on `ClassName`, but other than that, I think it's identical.
Yet, when I run this code, creating an `IList` with `IWebElements` works, but the following `IJavaScriptExecutor` throws an Invalid Cast exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection 1[System.Object]
>   to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList 1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]

Here's a bit of the code, this is for "text", I do the same for "num":

```
    // Find elements by class name
    IList<IWebElement> labels = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("text"));

    // get all input elements for every class label
    IList<IWebElement> labVals = (IList<IWebElement>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
        "var labels = arguments[0], labVals = []; for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++){" +
        "labVals.push(document.getElementById(labels[i].getAttribute('for'))); } return labVals;", labels);
```

I have looked at this question [Selenium Web Driver C# InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146513/selenium-web-driver-c-sharp-invalidcastexception-for-list-of-webelements-after-j) which may point to the same problem, but I don't see how the answers provided can help me.

An option could be to break up the `IJavaScriptExecutor` statement into "discrete" code with a work around, but I would not know how to do that.

Once I have the text labels and data values both in a `List` structure, I should be able to find the numbers I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cast error occurs because the IJavascriptExecutor outputs the general `System.Object` class [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I then try to cast to an `IWebElement`. This may work in some cases, but in this case it does not. Changing the receiving `IList` to `IList<Object>` solves the cast exception. With this the code runs, and then I found out with the debugger that all the data is captured with the first part of the code in the `Labels` list. The `IJavaScriptExecutor` returns null items only. So the second step is not required in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not using javascript, but it will work.
I would use a CssSelector method that receives throught parameters which column/row you need, and then you would be calling this method with loop to get all info from the page.

Checking the css of the page this is what I get from the first column/row

```
table.mdcTable > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(3) > td:nth-of-type(1)
```

So, the number "3" is related to the first row, and "1" is the first column. So we can make a method to return the exact element you want:

```
public IWebElement test(int line, int row)
    {
        return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(string.Format("table.mdcTable > tbody > tr:nth-of-type({}) > td:nth-of-type({})", line + 2, row)));
    }
```

Calling this method will return the element that has the text, so all you need to do is use 'element.Text' to the the value of the 'cell', or make the method return the text directly.

```
public String test(int line, int row)
    {
        return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(string.Format("table.mdcTable > tbody > tr:nth-of-type({}) > td:nth-of-type({})", line + 2, row))).Text;
    }
```

The only problem would be with the columns "Latest", because they do not only contain the numbers, but a bar. You would have to create a method to take care only of these column.

This would end up with something like this:

```
            try
            {
                int line = 1;
                int column = 1;
                while(column <= 7)
                    valueOfTheCell = test(line, column);
                getLatestGreen(line); //string.Format("tbody > tr:nth-of-type({0}) > td:nth-of-type(9) > span.text", line)
                getLatestRed(line);  //string.Format("tbody > tr:nth-of-type({0}) > td:nth-of-type(8) > span.text > b", line)
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                //Exception will be thrown when the code reaches the end of the list
            }
```

I won't say this is optimal, but it is an option.
If you want to do this way I can help you with any question or problem about how to use the selector.

Comment: @ Wermuth: Thanks for this alternative approach. Looks interesting as it seems to work without an external application. I will try it out.